# How to set the inflation of the costmap to represent a rectangle robot?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I looked at [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d#Inflation) but I don't understand how to configure the `costmap` to represent a rectangular robot. This question is a follow-up to [this one](https://answers.ros.org/question/298059/how-to-get-a-collision-free-path-in-a-known-map-with-move_base/) where I got a solution from David Lu which allows me to use `global_planner` alone to plan a path in a map (from an imported image).

**[UPDATE]**
As pavel92 advised me, I defined `footprint` and `inflation_radius` and it works fine. First, I thought it didn't work because the map resolution was too low and I couldn't see any difference because the obstacles remained rectangular, so I switched the resolution from 1 to 0.1 and made the map 10 times bigger.

First, I was confused with the meaning of the `inflation_radius`, but I found [this explanation](https://answers.ros.org/question/12874/costmap2d-inflation-radius/).

Here is the code:

### map.yml

```
image: map_obstacle400.png
resolution: 0.1
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
negate: 0
```

### map.png

[image: image description]

### roslaunch file

```
<launch>
  <node name="gp" pkg="global_planner" type="planner" output="screen">
  <rosparam>
  costmap:
    footprint: [[-2.5, -1.65], [-2.5, 1.65], [2.5, 1.65], [2.5, -1.65]]
    inflater_layer:
      inflation_radius: 0.7
    plugins:
      - {name: 'static_layer', type: 'costmap_2d::StaticLayer'}
      - {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
  </rosparam>
  </node>
  <node name="static_tf" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /base_link 100"/>
  <node name="map_srv" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/loic/Desktop/ROSAnswers2/map.yml"/>
</launch>
```

### call to /gp/make_plan

```
rosservice call /gp/make_plan "start:
  header:
    seq: 0
    stamp:
      secs: 0
      nsecs: 0
    frame_id: '/map'
  pose:
    position:
      x: 5.0
      y: 5.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
goal:
  header:
    seq: 0
    stamp:
      secs: 0
      nsecs: 0
    frame_id: '/map'
  pose:
    position:
      x: 30.0
      y: 30.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0"
```

### rviz

(run after the launch file, it show the map and the footprint, the path shows up after the `/gp/make_plan` call as expected)

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302153/how-to-set-the-inflation-of-the-costmap-to-represent-a-rectangle-robot?/) by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the navstack robot configuration [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup). Here under the Costmap Configuration you can see the common configuration for both global and local costmaps. Parameters such as the footprint of the robot usually go under the `costmap_common_params.yaml`  file. Here you can set the `footprint` parameter represent the robot as a polygon in both global and local costmaps. Example:

```
footprint: [[-0.5, -0.33], [-0.5, 0.33], [0.5, 0.33], [0.5, -0.33]]
```

I would advise using move base and using the planner plugins as parameters there. Here is an example of [husky navigation](https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/kinetic-devel/husky_navigation) that you can check out. 
In your case you can try putting the footprint parameter in your launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node name="gp" pkg="global_planner" type="planner" output="screen">
  <rosparam>
  costmap:
    footprint: [[-0.5, -0.33], [-0.5, 0.33], [0.5, 0.33], [0.5, -0.33]]
    plugins:
      - {name: 'static_layer', type: 'costmap_2d::StaticLayer'}
  </rosparam>
  </node>
  <node name="static_tf" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /base_link 100"/>
  <node name="map_srv" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/my_name/Desktop/path-planning/maps/map.yml"/>
</launch>
```

where you will enter the values for your robot's footprint.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-09-06**:
Thank for the advice, sorry for responding so late. Unfortunately, it doesn't change the path. I think there is something else to do to make it work. I updated my question.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-09-06**:
Ok so you got the footprint to work. The problem that u have now is that the global plan is too close to the obstacle right? As I can see from your RViz image, the inflation is not added. You will have to add the inflation layer as a plugin. This should add the 0.55 inflation around the obstacle

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-09-06**:
It should be something like this.

```
plugins:
     - {name: 'static_layer', type: 'costmap_2d::StaticLayer'}
    - {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

This should add the inflation around the obstacle and the global plan should be near it instead near the obstacle

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-09-06**:
Also forgot to mention that you should also put the inflation_radius under the inflation layer:

```
inflater_layer:
  inflation_radius: 0.55
```

Note that this is a workaround since the global planner does not take into account the footprint. That is usually done by the local planners

**Comment by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) on 2018-09-07**:
I managed to make it work. The resolution I was using was too low, so i couldn't see any difference. I updated my question. Thanks a lot!